# Fragment Loading issue android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onactivityresult

I have a problem by where a `FragmentActivity` on a tablet loads the `Fragment` `view` but doesn't display it unless its interacted with. So the view is loaded in via the main activity within an `onActivityResult()` function, all the code within the `Fragment` load fine because I can see the log cat logging all the information. But for some reason the `Fragment` is not visible, but if i press in an area where there is a button i.e. a back button, the `Fragment` appears and then disappears out (if the back button is called like it should). The event stranger thing is that if I take the fragment out of the `onActivityResult()` and call it in a button press, it works fine, so I know its not an xml issue or a java issue within the fragment. What I think it is, is the `onActivityResult()` function, but what I can't figure out is the fact that when I started to develop this application, and i implemented it the way I did, it worked fine.

The code for the function is below its the fragments within this function that are causing the problem, all the other fragments within the app are working fine. One other thing is that the application (including the fragments within this function) works fine on a phone, so that also indicates to me that its a tablet issue (also tested on two different tablets, samsung galaxy tab running 2.2.3 and nexus 7 running 4.3), so if anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    System.out.println("ACTIVITY RESULT");
    System.out.println("REQUEST CODE >>>>> " + requestCode);

    if (requestCode == webview) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            System.out.println("RESULT WEBVIEW");

            System.out.println(data.getStringExtra("URL"));

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("URL", data.getStringExtra("URL"));
            args.putString("List Name", currentList);
            args.putInt("List Position", pos);

            Fragment newFrag = new URLFragment();

            // newFrag.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = MainActivity.this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right,
                    R.anim.out_from_left);

            System.out.println("FRAG CONTAINER >>>> "
                    + findViewById(R.id.fragment_container));
            System.out.println("ARTICLE FRAG >>>> "
                    + findViewById(R.id.article_fragment));

            if (MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFrag,
                        "URL Fragment");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else {
                System.out.println("IS THIS TABLET?");

                transaction.add(R.id.article_fragment, newFrag,
                        "URL Fragment");
            }

            transaction.commit();

        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
            System.out.println("CANCELED WEBVIEW");
        }
    } else if (requestCode == camera) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            System.out.println("RESULT CAMERA");
            System.out.println(data.getData());

            if (data.getData().toString().contains("picasa")) {
                System.out.println("UNABLE TO LOAD IMAGE");
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "We are unable to load this image, please select a different one",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                        "Image Fragment") == null) {
                    GatherGalleryImages gatherImage = new GatherGalleryImages();
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri,
                            projection, null, null, null);

                    String selectedImagePath = gatherImage.getPath(cursor);

                    System.out.println(selectedImagePath);

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("List Name", currentList);
                    args.putInt("List Position", pos);
                    args.putString("Image Location", selectedImagePath);

                    CameraItemFragment newFragment = new CameraItemFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right,
                            R.anim.out_from_left);

                    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,
                                newFragment, "Image Fragment");
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    } else {

                        transaction.add(R.id.article_fragment, newFragment,
                                "Image Fragment");
                        // transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
            System.out.println("CANCELED CAMERA");
        }
    } else if (requestCode == IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                    requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult != null) {
                String upc = scanResult.getContents();

                // put whatever you want to do with the code here
                System.out.println("UPC >>>> " + upc);
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Webview_Activity.class);
                mainIntent.putExtra("upc", upc);
                mainIntent.putExtra("listName", currentList);

                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(mainIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    } else if (requestCode == cam) {
        System.out.println("CAMERA INTENT 0");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            String selectedImagePath = finalFile.getAbsolutePath();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("List Name", currentList);
            args.putInt("List Position", pos);
            args.putString("Image Location", selectedImagePath);

            CameraItemFragment newFragment = new CameraItemFragment();
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_right,
                    R.anim.out_from_left);

            if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment,
                        "Image Fragment");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            } else {

                transaction.add(R.id.article_fragment, newFragment,
                        "Image Fragment");
                // transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

    }

}
```

//EDIT

Ok so I have made a little discovery, the fragment is loading in fine but I have found that it is loading in behind the main fragment (the one set in xml as shown below) but only when called from the `onActivityResult()` function. The function is pointing to `headlines_fragment_two` but if I point it to `headlines_fragment` the fragment loads in front. Now I have already changed the name of `headlines_fragment_two` from `activity_fragment` to see if that would make any difference (sadly it didn't). So if anyone has any ideas why this is happening, please help. The xml code for the fragments layout on tablet is below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:name="com.package.name.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.99" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:background="#A6B5FAD9" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment_two"
        android:name="com.package.name.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using different layout for different resolutions? The problem might be in the construction of the layouts for the higher resolutions (tablets) then.

Comment: Ok so what I have found is that the code above, for some reason is making the fragments load in behind the main fragment (by main fragment i mean the one that i set in the xml file for the first load). I will edit the data to show the xml fragment layout

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, in one of my fragments I had an `onResume()` function that was calling the listFragment which for some reason was causing me a problem